# Leaky Bucket Example

Tags: communication, data, telephone, telecommunications, bit-rate

I have an image below of a leaky bucket image that I am trying to understand for my telecommunications class, and I was hoping for some guidance/verification if my train of thought is on the right track.

I am trying to determine the average and peak data rates, maximum burst length (bytes), and the time taken to transmit this maximum length burst.

**Bucket 1:**

Is it correct to say that the maximum capacity of this bucket is N1 = 700? I am not sure what the unit of this capacity is, I think it might be tokens - Is this correct? Can I say that in this case, tokens = packets, as the image states '1 token per packet'? Also, a new token will arrive at bucket 1 at a maximum rate of 480 us - Is my understanding correct?

**For bucket 2:**

The bucket can only hold 1 token, and a new token can arrive at bucket 2 at a maximum rate of 80us.

I was wondering, is there any way I can determine the rate at which tokens are released from each bucket? The rate of arrival for each bucket is given, but I am not sure about the rate of release.

I appreciate any guidance and help. Thank you :)

[image]